# How to group months column in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, date, correlation, data-handling

I have a data frame in the following fashion :

```
Year <- 1948:2017
Jan<- rnorm(70)
Feb<- rnorm(70)
Mar<- rnorm(70)
Apr<- rnorm(70)
May<- rnorm(70)
Jun<- rnorm(70)
Jul<- rnorm(70)
Aug<- rnorm(70)
Sep<- rnorm(70)
Oct<- rnorm(70)
Nov<- rnorm(70)
Dec<- rnorm(70)
test_df <- cbind.data.frame(Year, Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec)
head(test_df)
########Console result


    Year        Jan        Feb        Mar         Apr
1 1948 -0.5918300  0.0497792 -0.9302350  0.73162688
2 1949 -1.2731259  0.8933090  0.2340527  1.03077077
3 1950 -0.3727786 -0.5680272  1.4439980  0.53150414
4 1951  0.6520741 -1.4229818 -0.9700416 -0.07151535
5 1952  0.4296101 -0.2294352  1.0863566  1.58652232
6 1953  0.3334147 -0.5386016  1.3432490  1.91005906
          May        Jun         Jul         Aug
1  0.28268233  0.7870373 -0.06178119 -0.14469371
2 -0.02048683 -1.4834607 -0.17926819 -0.38662117
3  0.24659095  0.4929837  0.79430914  0.03486687
4 -0.60123934  1.1304690 -0.13452649 -1.07814801
5  1.39161546  0.6827090  0.54729206  0.50188908
6 -0.53882956 -0.3246258  0.09602686 -2.35509441
         Sep        Oct        Nov         Dec
1  2.0492817  0.6185466  2.0427045 -0.06097253
2  0.7804505 -0.3416864 -1.5192509  2.01911948
3  1.9193976 -0.3120360  1.5646020 -0.04911313
4 -0.1147404 -0.3593639  0.5186583  1.39936930
5  2.4481574 -1.2349037 -0.3519640  0.58429371
6  0.6639531 -0.4471403  0.7071486 -1.02036467
```

I require to group random months such as `JanFeb`, `JanMar` or `AprFeb` or `MarMayNov`, like so. The grouping of months could be anything (Many number of possibilities and combinations). And when I group this months their values should be averages as for example, `JanFeb` value should be the mean of the values of `Jan` and `Feb` or `MarMayNov` value should be the mean of `Mar`, `Nov` and `May`. How to approach this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

###### Edit

Lets say for simplicity that I only want to group 2 months or 3 months at most not more than that.

Comment: So the highest possible grouping would be ```JanFebMarApr....Dec```? Right? Also, if you don't need to group them by year, then you can just take the average for each month and reduce the number of rows to 1.

Comment: That can be done with `rowMeans()` as well. What if I only want to group 2 or 3 months at most?

Answer (score 3):

We can create all possible combinations of names using `lapply` and `combn`. For each combination find the average of selected columns in one column and combine such columns together in one dataframe.

```
cols <- names(test_df)[-1]

result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(2:length(cols), function(x)
  do.call(cbind, combn(cols, x, function(y) 
    setNames(data.frame(rowMeans(test_df[y])), 
              paste0(y, collapse = "")), simplify = FALSE))))
```

If you want to combine only 3 months at most, change `2:length(cols)` to `2:3` in `lapply`.

Comment: Is there a bug in your code? The 1st `lapply` calls `function(x)` but `x` is never used and `combn` only combines 2 `cols`. Is `x` intended to be where 2 is?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thanks for pointing that out @RuiBarradas